# What signals it's better to handle in a TCP server?

Tags: c, tcp, signals, handle

I'm writing a TCP server.
Everything it has to do is to read/write text to/from TCP sockets and read/write this text to/from text files on the file system where the server runs.

If there's a problem with the connection (e.g. the client closes the socket), the server blocked on a read/write receives a SIGPIPE signal. I want to ignore it: the server simply closes its socket's end because the communication is now impossible.
Is it a good way?

Are there other signals I've to consider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many server programs choose to ignore `SIGPIPE`, and use the return codes from `read`/`write` to have better understanding of the disconnection. For example, `read`/`recv` returns `0` on a proper disconnect from the other end, and `-1` on error with `errno` set to one of multiple alternatives.

Comment: `sendto`/`sendmsg` can take a flag to avoid generating `SIGPIPE`, which is also a decent alternative. I never want ugly dependencies between my networking code and my signal handling code (if any), so I always use either this method or block `SIGPIPE` around the sending code and remove and possible pending `SIGPIPE` before unblocking it. This avoids altering or depending on the global state (signal disposition) of the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

You could also implement an interrupt handler, in case the server crashes you may want to do some operations before closing.

e.g. [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29)

```
void interrupt_handler(int sig){
    endloop = 1;
    close(sd);
    printf("Interrupt recieved: shutting down server!\n");
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    //all typical TCP socket functions

    signal(SIGINT, interrupt_handler);

    while(!endloop){

      //service loop

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the server is a daemon process, it's a common practice to use `SIGHUP` to restart or re-initialize the server. @Joachim's answer is the most important, however: client behaviour shouldn't cause the server to terminate.

**Note:** Being asynchronous, there are [restrictions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-reent/index.html) on what signal *handlers* can do, safely.

Comment: It would be nice to elaborate on the last point, and note that unless you're an expert with the rules of signal handling, it's probably best not to do anything in the signal handler but instead inform the main program flow that it needs to act at the next opportunity (e.g. with a self-pipe).